# Rebuild an index in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

When I execute this query, my `.MDF` file grows by 120 GB:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON TABLE_NAME REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90)
```

or

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON TABLE_NAME REBUILD
```

Can you tell me how to avoid database growth before/after rebuilding the index? I am de-fragmenting the index.

Comment: Please provide more information. What is the DDL of your table, how large is it, etc. What was your fillfactor before the rebuild? What is the definitiion of your index?

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server are you using?  When an index is rebuilt (and remember that a clustered index IS the table), SQL picks up all the data and puts it back down again.  Try reorganize instead.  But that may not work depending on the fragmentation level.  Each index rebuild operation should be about the size of the table so very large tables will use a lot of log space.  You can specify SORT_IN_TEMPDB which will put the pressure there instead, but log backups will still be larger than normal after a defragmentation cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the FILLFACTOR? Having a fill factor of 90 means that 10% of the index pages will be empty (but still allocated in the MDF). If the current page fullness is above 90% the space needed will increase with a rebuild.

If you are simply just rebuilding the index, the space is still needed to actually create the whole index again. If the space is an issue, look into gradually reorganizing the index instead by allowing it to run for a few hours (for example) and then killing the job. The good work it has done so far will be retained. I would do this one index at a time however.

```
ALTER INDEX <index_name> ON <table_name> REORGANIZE;
```

EDIT: It's worth noting that reorganizing will still require a large amount of transaction log and you cannot change the FILLFACTOR with this command.